# com.day.cq.dam.commons.util,version=[1.50,2) -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: aem

I'm trying to run AEM 6.5 however i'm running into an issue below:

com.day.cq.dam.commons.util,version=[1.50,2) -- Cannot be resolved

It can boot up Author, but there is no content and it looks like that's the only source of the error I can see.

Comment: How did you try to start AEM? Quickstart, startup or the jar? Which content is not there? Where do you get that issue? Are any bundles not starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the maven dependency in your pom.xml and build and install the code in AEM and check if this issue still exists.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq.dam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-dam-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```